# Jquery validation place all errors in single div with li element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I want to display all the validation errors under single div with `li` element.

Following is **my code**

```
$("#login_form").validate({
        showErrors: function (errorMap, errorList) {
            $("#error_list").html('');
            this.defaultShowErrors();
            if (!this.numberOfInvalids()) {
                $(".error_container").hide();
            }
        },
        rules: {
            username: {
                required: true
            },
            password: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            username: {
                required: "Please enter username."
            },
            password: {
                required: "Please enter password."
            }
        },
        errorElement : 'li',
        errorLabelContainer: '#error_list',
        highlight: function(element) {
            $(".error_container").show();
        }
    });
```

**Html :**

```
<div class="error_container" {{count($errors) ? '' : 'hidden'}}>
  <div class="error_wrapper">
    <ul id="error_list">
      @if(count($errors))
        @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
         <li class="error">{{$error}}</li>
        @endforeach
      @endif
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

It's working fine but errors hide and show are not working properly.

I just want to simply place **all validation errors** which I get after submitting to function **in single `div`**.

Comment: Do you want to display errors after submitting form?

Comment: @PankajMakwana, Yes.

Comment: You got error messages in that section, now again you are submitting again then errors should be hide, if validation not success then show those errors right?

Comment: @PankajMakwana add a errorPlacement: function after highlight function.

Comment: @ Akshay Deshmukh  So, You want to add Collapse in error display section?

Comment: @SarvanKumar, That's what I did, but my div has some CSS like background color, because of what I am hiding it in page load. Div should be shown or hide like collapse like "AddWeb Solution Pvt Ltd" said

Comment: @all solved it and added the solution in Answer If anyone needs it. Thank for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the error by updating following code

```
  showErrors: function (errorMap, errorList) {
                   //$("#error_list").html('');       // Removed from here
                    this.defaultShowErrors();
                    if (!this.numberOfInvalids()) {
                        $(".error_container").hide();
                        $("#error_list").html('');     // Placed here
                    }
                },
```